# How to check the page load times of pages generated by Mobify-js

Tags: html, mobify-js

I am looking for measuring the time required for loading a page which has been generated by Mobify-js. As mentioned on the website, when the js is used, the page load times is optimizated. So, I wanted to understand, against what benchmarks (original) file can I measure the performance of mobify-js.

One thing that comes to my mind is, simply removing the import of the mobify-js for a sample page like "resizeImages-img-element/index.html" in the source code, and comparing the page load times of with and without mobify-js. Mobify-js  community, any thoughts on the same? Any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some timing data about the different parts of the Mobify transformation by looking at `Mobify.timing.points`. Using this you can measure the time difference between when the page begins loading and a collection of different events.

`// Measure time between 'finished document' and 'DOMContentLoaded'
var loadTime = Mobify.timing.points[11][0] - Mobify.timing.points[0][0]`

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @tedtate. I will check the code and get back in case I need further help.